# Removing Hashbang from URL in AngularJs Route

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I am new in angularJs. I just tried to route pages in angularJs. It's working but '#' symbol is shown. So I have used

```
$locationProvider and $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but it's not working. So I am giving my code bellow to seek for a help to find the problem. I am using CDN of angularJs.

The project Structure is:

[image]

app.Js File is

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'ngRoute']);

angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/view1', {
            controller: 'Controller1',
            templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html'
        })
        .when('/view2', {
            controller: 'Controller2',
            templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //activate HTML5 Mode
});
```

**Controller is:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('Controller1', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello, world";
    })
    .controller('Controller2', function ($scope) {
        $scope.now = new Date();
    });
```

**Html Page is:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Routing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/view2">view2</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-view></ng-view>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>    
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base should be your project folder path. In your case

```
<base href="/untitled1/">
```

Also I hope you are handling the page refresh redirection through .htaccess

Refer [this link](https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/) for more info in this

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. but it's not working. still showing 404 Not Found. Do you think there is something wrong with CDN version.